# Fastest way to make SNES Style pixel art?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, pixelation, pixel-art

I'm trying to make an illustration as SNES pixel art and I think it takes a lot of time. I'm not sure if I could do it for myself or is an idea too hard for a particular creator.

Idea is that this illustration :

[image]

Become like this one (of Megaman X SNES):

[image]

So, maybe I'm thinking too much complicated for a particular job, but I want to ask if someone knows a 'fastest way' to reach this pixel art quality in few days of work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to be blunt. Hire a pixel artist. Pixel art is one of those disciplines where you can barely cut any corners. If you do, the art looks bad and more like it has been downscaled to low-res rather than like actual pixel art. Put in the work and learn pixel art (which is impossible to do in a couple months, let alone days), or hire a professional with experience.

That said, there are multiple pixel artists who offer affordable 'resource packs' or 'asset bundles' with tilesets and other collections of small elements. With the right pack, you can piece together your illustration from those tiles.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation!